# I get 'undefined' output for my flash as2 rss feed once LIVE in browser

Tags: xml, flash, rss, actionscript-2

I get an 'undefined' output for my flash as2 rss feed once it's LIVE on the browser. It works fine when I test it locally, but once it goes LIVE it displays 'undefined'. My code is below.

Now I did research this and found out that it could be a security measure via the browser or a cross-domain issue. I also tried mirroring this rss feed in google feedburner. Although it only works on an opera browser. Any suggestions would be great. Rather if I have to write some actionscript in the file to allow the browsers to reed the feed.

Below is the code that one of you guys have graciously helped me with.

```
xmlLoad.onLoad = function(e) {
  var xmlItems:XMLNode = xmlLoad.firstChild.firstChild;
  var itemlink:String,itemtitle:String,itemdesc:String = '';

  for (var m:Number = 0; m<xmlItems.childNodes.length; m++) {
     if (xmlItems.childNodes[m].nodeName == "item") {
        var article:Array = xmlItems.childNodes[m].childNodes
        itemlink = itemtitle = itemdesc = '';
        for (var n:Number = 0; n<article.length; n++) {             
            switch (article[n].nodeName) {
                case "link":
                    itemlink=article[n].firstChild.toString();  
                    break;
                case "title":
                    itemtitle=article[n].firstChild.toString();  
                    break;  
                case "description":
                    itemdesc=article[n].firstChild.nodeValue;  
                    break;
            }              
        }

       xml_text+= "<a href=\""+itemlink+"\"><u>"+itemtitle+"</u></a><br>"+itemdesc+"<br><br>";
     }   
       }   

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont be abble to access this feed directly because there is a `crossdomain.xml` file set on the server that only allows a restricted list of domains to access this feed : http://www.astrology.com/crossdomain.xml. More about crossdomain.xml [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html).

You can bypass this with the help of a server side script such as PHP to act as a proxy between your SWF and the feed.

**Example in PHP**

proxy.php

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

echo file_get_contents('http://www.astrology.com/horoscopes/monthly-overview.rss');
?>
```

In flash, you call :

```
xmlLoad.load("/path/to/proxy.php");
```

*Please accepts answers when it [solves the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you posted.*